# How to get the location of a section in C code

Tags: c

In the linker script, I have defined

```
MEMORY {
  sec_1 : ORIGIN = 0x1B800, LENGTH = 2048
  ......
}
```

How can I read the start address of this section in C? I would like to copy it in a variable in the C code

Comment: Question is not clear to me. Do you have a file with the content `MEMORY { sec_1 : ORIGIN = 0x1B800, LENGTH = 2048 ...` and you want to read and parse this file so you can set a variable in your c code to the value `origin=0x1B800`?

Comment: Yes, because I need to have a variable that its value is equal to the start address of that section (sec_1)

Comment: Given the code you showed, you are using the GCC toolchain. Correct?

Comment: Yes I'm using it

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't do that. To read and parse a file you need to open the file `fopen()`, read it `fread()`,`fgets()` or similar and then parse it. Are you sure you want to read and parse the file?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 quite a bold step to claim, the answer accepted by the author does not suit the purpose asked for... Did you consider a misperception on your side? Obviously Davide does not intend to parse the linker file but wants to have the address assigned by the linker at runtime of the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically to achieve this, you have two tasks to fulfill:

1. Tell the linker to save the start address of the section. This can be achieved by placing a symbol in the linker script at the beginning of your section.
2. Tell the compiler to save initialize a constant with an address filled in later by the linker

As for the first step: In your section `sec_1` you have to place a symbol that will be placed at the start of that section:

```
SECTIONS
{
    ...
    .sec_1 : 
    {
        __SEC_1_START = ABSOLUTE(.); /* <-- add this */
        ...
    } > sec_1
    ...
}
```

Now that the linker produces bespoke symbol, you have to make it accessible from the compiler side. In order to do so, you need somewhere some code like this:

```
/* Make the compiler aware of the linker symbol, by telling it, there 
   is something, somewhere that the linker will put together (i.e. "extern") */
extern int __SEC_1_START;

void Sec1StartPrint(void) {
    void * const SEC_1_START = &__SEC_1_START;
    printf("The start address for sec_1 is: %p", SEC_1_START);
}
```

By calling `Sec1StartPrint()` you should get an address output that matches your `*.map` file the linker created.

Comment: I'll try and I'll let you know. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Davide Just for fun I decided to undust my setup a bit and quickly try it myself. for me following the instructions above, worked as expected.

Comment: Ok I tried It and It works. How can I do the sane for the lenght? In my example It Easy equal ti 2048

Comment: @Davide Typically you would place two symbols embracing the section in question (in your example: have a `__SEC_1_START` just as above and place `__SEC_1_END` version of it just at the very end before the closing brace) and then either calculate the difference or use `__SEC_1_END` as upper limit for your loops.